# How to convert emoji unicode in android

Tags: android, emoji

In anroid emoji convert to unicode time alwasy get output  U+5c but we give emoji string "\uD83D\uDE21" this method it's working

```
String a = emojiconEditText.getText().toString().trim();
String text = new String(
    StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(a).getBytes(),
    StandardCharsets.UTF_8
);
int codepoint = text.codePointAt(0);
String yourUnicode = "U+"+Integer.toHexString(codepoint);
```

Comment: You need to create a mapping of your emoji and replace string where necessary with the corresponding UTF-16 encoded value.

Comment: @GiddyNaya please update sample code here. i try many ways but not working. we directly give value "" below like it's working   String text = new String("\uD83D\uDE01".getBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8); but value assigned variable passing time it's not working

Answer (score 1):

You can encode/decode emojis to the following unicode `UTF-8, UTF-16` and `U+<hex>` using the below:

```
try {
    //I am assuming you are getting unicode from an inputbox
    String emoji = emojiconEditText.getText().toString().trim();
    //I am also assuming you are getting emoji in hexadecimal form `U+<hexdigits>`
    String unicodeHexEmoji = "U+";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 

    //Firstly you want to encode emojis to unicode types by converting to byte array
    byte[] utf8Bytes = emoji.getBytes("UTF-8"); // "\\uf0\\u9f\\u98\\u80"
    byte[] utf16Bytes = emoji.getBytes("UTF-16"); // "\\ud83d\\ude00" 

    //convert emoji to hex
    for (byte b : utf16Bytes ) {
        sb.append(String.format("%02x", b));
    }
    //we are converting our current emoji to hex just for the purpose of this example
    unicodeHexEmoji += sb; //yields "U+feffd83dde21";
    byte[] utfHexBytes = getByteFromHex(unicodeHexEmoji.replace("U+","")); // "\\ud83d\\ude00"  
   //NB: we removed "U+" because its only a prefix denoting that the string is a <hex>

    //Decoding our unicodes back to emoji string 
    String emojiUTF_8 = new String(utf8Bytes,"UTF-8");
    String emojiUTF_16 = new String(utf16Bytes,"UTF-16");
    String emojiUTF_hex = new String(utfHexBytes,"UTF-16");
    Log.d("Tag", "emojiUTF_8 : "+ emojiUTF_8); 
    Log.d("Tag", "emojiUTF_16 : "+ emojiUTF_16)
    Log.d("Tag", "emojiUTF_hex : "+ emojiUTF_hex)
    //output
    //emojiUTF-8 : 
    //emojiUTF-16 : 
    //emojiUTF-hex : 

} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

...
public byte[] getByteFromHex(String hexString){
 //To convert hex string to byte array, you need to first get the length
 //of the given string and include it while creating a new byte array.
 byte[] val = new byte[hexString.length() / 2];
 for (int i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
  int index = i * 2;
  int j = Integer.parseInt(hexString.substring(index, index + 2), 16);
  val[i] = (byte) j;
 }
 return val; 
}
```